# EF Code First Migrations: MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion without NUGET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I need help to clarify how EF Code First Migrations works on production machine.
I've some entity classes and DbContext-derived class to access entities. Now, I want to perform these several things:

- when my application starts, it must create database, if database does not exists;
- then database schema must be adjusted to the model;
- if database was created just now, I want to create some indexes;
- also, if database was created just now, it must be seeded by some initial data;
- all of these things must be performed automatically, without any NUGET commands or external tools.

I've read some articles about migrations, but they're focused mostly on NUGET usage or pure automatic database updates at run-time (via `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`). I know about `DbMigration` class, but I can't understand, how to glue together `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` strategy and `DbMigration`.

**UPDATE.**
In fact, I cannot use NUGET in the project and I need possibility to make a migration "by hand".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply use `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`.

> when my application starts, it must create database, if database does not exists;

`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` will do that

> then database schema must be adjusted to the model;

`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` will do that

> if database was created just now, I want to create some indexes;

Create code based initial migration for your database and `Sql` method in `Up` method to define all indexes you need.

> also, if database was created just now, it must be seeded by some initial data;

Again use `Sql` in initial migration or `Seed` method in migration configuration

> all of these things must be performed automatically, without any NUGET commands or external tools

NuGet and commands will help you to prepare it in design time (but you can simply reference required assemblies and write all code yourselves). Runtime doesn't need any powershell commands.

`DbMigrator` is for scenarios where you don't want to use `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` and you want to control migration from your code.

Comment: "code based initial migration" is a `DbMigration` descendant, right? How CF will know, that `MyInitialMigration : DbMigration` must be applied right now?

Comment: `Add-Migration` command will create `DbMigration` class for you but this class has also second auto-generated part where `IMigrationMetadata` interface is implemented. This interface defines Id property. I think the ordinal value of Id is increasing with every migration so the migrator uses the Id to apply migrations in correct order and to find which migrations were already applied.

Comment: Hmm... I see. `IMigrationMetadata` provides hash values for model before and after applying specific migration. This means, that I can't implement `IMigrationMetadata` by hand, without using NUGET, doesn't it? Or there is some public API, which can calculate has for the model? I cannot use NUGET (updated the question).

Comment: my project being built with CC.NET, and it doesn't support references to NuGet packages currently.

Comment: But that should not limit you in using NuGet in Visual studio where you need to run those PowerShell commands.

Comment: I've tried to execute `Enable-Migrations` command without adding reference to EF via NuGet. It doesn't work.

Comment: MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion failed to create the database for us. We are using LocalDb. Perhaps that is the problem? After I created the mdf file manually (via Visual Studio) Update-Database worked fine

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, SetInitializer(MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion) doesn´t create the SDF file, at least on SQLCE. Weirdly it work if I call new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion().InitializeDatabase(context)

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I've created my custom initializer and I want to move my migrations at several deployment destination. Do you prefer deploying migrations using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion or by generating sql commands using Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: InitialMigration -TargetMigration: TargetMigration and running commads for different deployment target?

Comment: @RudolfDvoracek: I don't like magic tools when it comes to production environment. I would use script and test it on database backup (if possible) before deploying it. If the target is test environment I would probably use the simplest possible version - either MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion or some build script executing update-database.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Thank you very much for your recommendations. What if I use script generating and running it against target database. Is possible to use this scenario, when running application is web application and compiled model hasn't been updated in binaries at production environment? Could it raise exception because model is older than database schema?

Comment: @RudolfDvoracek: If you set database initializer to null it may work if the model is still compatible with the database. If your application knows about migration existence it will throw exception because model hash stored in _MigrationHistory table will not match the hash of current model.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Thank you for this important piece of information. I decided to use MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion in my code.